# Why the transmitted pulse in pulse-echo technique cannot be too long?

Tags: reflection

**Question.** An ultrasound pulse-echo technique is used to produce an image by reflection from many boundaries. If the transmitted pulse is too long, the image produced is of poor quality. Why?

---

**My attempt.** If the transmitted pulse is too long, then the pulse contains many wavelengths. After that, I would receive pulses containing the same number of wavelengths but with lower intensity. Then I am stuck. I even wonder why the transmitted pulse cannot be replace by *continuous* ultrasound so that we could have continuous reflected image. Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has more to do with signal processing than physics per se. A pulse is usually a chirp, i.e. an increasing or decreasing frequency signal. You could dilate it but if you keep all subbands active all the time then you have no way to determine a start or a end to the band signal so no way to calculate delays either. Delays are what is used to compute distances using this type of imaging. The longer the sound takes to feed back the sampler, the farther the target is assumed to be located. So you need a way to precisely determine the timing of what comes in and back. Also some frequencies can be absorbed by the material so the pulse is designed to send a wide range of frequencies at once. But it has to be short so you know what pulse number you are going to listen to next. Optimizations can be made so as to send multiple pulses before the first comes back, it just gets more complicated to make sure which is which.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It really helps my understanding. But I am still confused with this sentence "But it has to be short so you know what pulse number you are going to listen to next." Do you mind clarifying it a bit more? What do you mean by "pulse number" and what happens when the pulse is long? Thank you very much! @Exocytosis

Comment: @IncredibleSimon In order to calculate travel time, you have to know when the signal you're listening to was emitted. If your pulses are long enough that they blend together, so that you can't distinguish one from another, how do you know when the signal you're listening to was emitted?

Comment: By pulse number I just mean the ordering of the pulses. If you send two pulses and after that you start to hear something, you may assume you are listening to pulse number one. But that can be wrong reasoning if you are not sending the pulse to the same target (and typically, you will scan an object so you will keep changing the beam orientation). If the first pulse was sent to a very deep hole in the object, the second pulse's echo could arrive first. A long pulse is not a problem per se. It will just slow you down because you need to end it before the next sample location.

Comment: Actually if you get a bad quality with long pulses, it has to do with the implementation itself. You need to give more specifics. But in general, longer pulse does NOT mean worse picture. It just takes more time. Actually the only reason I can see for a quality degradation is if you have the same time for scanning the entire picture whatever the pulse duration. In that case, longer pulses would mean less pixels, so a lower resolution. But again, this is implementation specific.

Comment: I think I roughly got it. Your explanation is indeed thorough. Thank you! Let me tick your answer. <3 @Exocytosis

Comment: Actually, one more curious question: if I transmit ultrasound continuously, would the transmitted wave interfere with the reflected wave so that I could recognize the 'delay'? Thanks. @Exocytosis

Comment: It depends on what you mean by continuous ultrasound. If by that you mean a superposition of sines that do not vary with time, then you have no way to tell where the signal starts. However, if by that you mean sending a time varying sound (in amplitude and/or frequency) then you have an opportunity to make correlations between what you sent and what you heard. It is like if you listen to the thunder and count the time between the flash and the noise. If there are too many lightnings how can you know which is which and find its approximate distance?

Comment: Regarding the interference between what is sent and what is reflected, this does not usually happen because the incident sound does not move the material very much. Now if you sent knives at a pack of butter, you would change the shape all the time. But ultrasound is usually low energy.

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you so much buddy. I understand as that basically without transmitting in pulses, the received wave pattern would be like disaster and hard to analyze. @Exocytosis